# Power series $x^n/n$ with one plus, then two minuses, then three plusses, and so on

Tags: nt.number-theory, special-functions, power-series

Which function is represented by the powerseries

$$1-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{x^3}{4}+\frac{x^4}{5}+\frac{x^5}{6}-\frac{x^6}{7}-\frac{x^7}{8}-\frac{x^8}{9}-\frac{x^9}{10} + \dots$$
(one plus, then two minuses, then three plusses, then four minuses, and so on)?

I tried to sum the convergent series

$$1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{10} + \dots$$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753960, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414431

Comment: Series is easily evaluated in PARI-GP as s = sumalt(n=1,(-1)^(n-1)*(harmonic(n*(n+1)/2)-harmonic(n*(n-1)/2))) = 0.51710037904240172506481077213135745047...

Answer (score 18):

The answer is in terms of theta functions. Let $$\Psi(q)=1+q+q^3+q^6+q^{10}+q^{15}+\cdots;$$ this is a Jacobi theta function that can be written as $q^{-1/8}\eta^2(2\tau)/\eta(\tau)$ where $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$ and $\eta(\tau)$ is the Dedekind eta function. See for example Section 2 of the paper by Ono, Robins and Wahl, "On the representation of integers as sums of triangular numbers".

**Edit:** We need a closely related power series $$\bar\Psi(q)=1-q+q^3-q^6+q^{10}-q^{15}+\cdots.$$ Of course, this is not $\Psi(-q)$ as I first wrote! Presumably it's a theta function, but I don't know how to express it in terms of the Dedekind eta function.

Then $$(2\bar\Psi(x)-1)/(1-x)=1-x-x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5-x^6-x^7-x^8-x^9+x^{10}+\cdots$$ is the derivative of ($x$ times your power series) with respect to $x$.

*Ono, Ken; Robins, Sinai; Wahl, Patrick T.*, [**On the representation of integers as sums of triangular numbers**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01831114), Aequationes Math. 50, No. 1-2, 73-94 (1995). [ZBL0828.11057](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0828.11057).

Comment: This $\overline\Psi$ is listed at OEIS as: "Expansion of false theta series variation of Ramanujan theta function psi(x)."  https://oeis.org/A197870  It does not show an eta function version.

Comment: Thanks! "False theta function" does seem to sum it up, and explains why I couldn't find a way to express it in terms of the eta function. The function $q^{-1/8}\eta^3(\tau)=1-3q+5q^3-7q^6+9q^{10}-11q^{15}+\cdots$ seems closely related, but doesn't quite do the trick.